# UI for a trading application in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have created a [trading application in WPF](http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?cid=15&lid=579), for which I am ashamed of it's shabby look since it is far from being impressive.
I would now like to redesign the user interface for my application, and make it similar to [an example screen shot of a trading application](http://mdavey.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/statarbetf.jpg)

Can someone please advice tips on what path I should follow to make a UI of similar nature? eg., if there is an open source C# WPF application which has a similar look and feel, that would be great. or if there is a library which has cool listview, scrollbar and progress bars, ..

PS: I do not have microsoft blend

Comment: Whatever answer you end up getting, implementing this without Blend will be painful.  I'd recommend you get yourself a copy :)

Comment: You have many TextBoxes and redundant information, whereas that application doesn't require to use keyboard at all. UI of this nature is built using Expanders, ListView (or DataGrid) and ItemsControl (or ListBox).

Comment: thanks for the tips, i never used expander before and will look into it. i have another question. It seems there are a group of multiple windows glued to one another at the sides, or are they embedded inside a parent windows?

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the MVVM pattern for creating UI's for wpf application
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090025

Refer the josh smith blog for WPF MVVM
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/a-guided-tour-of-wpf/

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you would have completed your application by now. If not:

Try understanding the sample [Stock Trader Reference Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) application by MSDN built using WPF, MVVM, and [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) and you would get a head start for creating your kind of UI and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it as a suggestion not an answer exactly. But posting for those who are new to WPF and learning screen designing or patterns. According to my experience with WPF I can say first get you hands dirty learn how binding works because that is the base of WPF.Simpler way to learn how binding works is learning how to bind controls with other controls. Then use simple classes and learn MVVM. Next go for command binding within MVVM perimeter. Keep the prism to the last, because you need good understanding of binding mechanisms, commands, MVVM and more to understand PRISM. After this you will have idea of how these things work together and will help you figure out how to play with data and screen together and design nice screens. Again, Not an answer to the above question. Just suggestions to those who are learning WPF and landed here looking for WPF UI designing.